# Manage Internet connection for a program

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-networking

I am using a Windows 7 PC with 2 network cards.

One for a public line and one for an internal line behind a proxy.

Is there a way or a software program where I can manage which program (Outlook, WM) uses which Internet connection or network card?

Using the option of `interface metric` is not what I am looking for. Someone also suggested me ZoneAlarm, but I dislike this program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/

It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that forcebindip has with not being able to inject itself into a forked process can be fixed by setting as a debugger on the executable.  In addition, by setting it via the registry, you no longer need to alter each shortcut to an application.  See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed.aspx for instructions.