# Manage internet connection per program

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-networking

I already saw this post where I can find forcebind

[Manage Internet connection for a program](https://superuser.com/questions/125600/manage-internet-connection-for-a-program)

I can not understand how can I use it to force all the programs to use a internet connection and create a whitelist or something to allow the usage to the other internet connection. (I'm not an expert on windows or network management). I don't have access to any router or hardware at all, I'm trying to use every network card i have connected to an internet conection wisely because one of them is a completely open to use but limited at download, and the other is very restricted but not limited.

If it exists a program with graphical interface that allow me to do this, I really appreciated that.

(Sorry for not create a comment or something in the link above, i don't have reputation to do that)

Comment: Are you trying to define a group of applications per interface ? It seems to me ForceBindIP alone cannot do that, but a threaded script might do the trick, if nothing else exists.

Comment: How could I do that?, and yes, I want to create a group per interface.

Comment: You'd have to program it yourself with your preferred programming language.